# Repetir un bucle

Tags: php, loops

Necesito repetir una acción 9999999999999999 veces en PHP.

Realicé un bucle for:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 9999999999999999; $i++)
```

Pero me da un error y no ejecuta el bucle. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Qué error te muestra?, y sería más fácil ayudarte si proporcionas el código.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la finalidad de repetir tantas veces el ciclo?, seguramente te arroja un error de tiempo de ejecución excedido

Answer (score 1):

Una posibilidad (dada la falta de información) es que estés corriendo el PHP en un sistema operativo de 32 bits, donde 9999999999999999 es mayor al máximo entero manejable (el valor de la constante `PHP_INT_MAX`, que en 32 bits es 2147483647, y en 64 bits es 9223372036854775807)

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. Aunque tu respuesta parece correcta, solemos esperar a que quien pregunto, aclare su pregunta para no entrar en un cumulo de comentarios si no estabas en lo correcto. Gracias!